# Converting serialdate to DateTime

Tags: c#

I pass 41866 to this method and i get 16/8/2014. Yet the spreadsheet I'm importing says 15/8/2014, huh!!!!!

```
private DateTime GetDate(int serialDate)
{
    return new DateTime(1899, 12, 31).AddDays(serialDate);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are different epoch dates. According to [Epoch (reference date)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_%28reference_date%29) (reformatted):

---

*Epoch date*: **December 30, 1899**

*Notable uses*: Microsoft COM DATE, Object Pascal, LibreOffice Calc

*Rationale for selection*: Technical internal value used by Microsoft Excel; for compatibility with Lotus 1-2-3.

---

*Epoch date*: [**January 0, 1900**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/January_0)

*Notable uses*: Microsoft Excel, Lotus 1-2-3

*Rationale for selection*: While logically January 0, 1900 is equivalent to December 31, 1899, these systems do not allow users to specify the latter date.

---

So in your case, perhaps `1899-12-30` is day `0`, `1899-12-31` is day `1`.